# Problem when I want to work on a different version in Ionic dashboard

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a version deployed in the Ionic dashboard, and every time that I'm working on a new version and the device is connected to the Internet, it's replacing my version with the version that is deployed there. How can I work on a new version?

Comment: can you explain your question clearly?

Comment: Sorry, I just get this code to continue the project. So, I know that we can deploy a version using the ionic dashboard. My problem is, I'm working on some new tasks, another branch, make some changes on the project, but when building the code for my device, my changes showed just for a while, when I close the app and reopen it, the device gets the version that I had before, without my changes. So I've noticed that it gets the last version deployed on the ionic dashboard. I sad about the connection to the internet, because if it's not connected, my changes still there.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your device is connected to internet or not, using [this network plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/network/) provided by ionicframework.

```
let disconnectSubscription = this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => { console.log('network was disconnected :-(');});
```

This metod will automatically catch if user disconnected their network and

```
let connectSubscription = this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {console.log('network connected!');});
```

using this method you can catch if user is connected to network. 
So using those method you can show/hide some content for offline and online use.

I have created network service to catch Online and Offline status :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network/ngx'
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
 
export enum ConnectionStatus {
  Online,
  Offline
}
 
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NetworkService {
 
  private status: BehaviorSubject<ConnectionStatus> = new BehaviorSubject(ConnectionStatus.Offline);
 
  constructor(private network: Network, private toastController: ToastController, private plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then(() => {
      this.initializeNetworkEvents();
      let status =  this.network.type !== 'none' ? ConnectionStatus.Online : ConnectionStatus.Offline;
      this.status.next(status);
    });
  }
 
  public initializeNetworkEvents() {
 
    this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
        this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Offline);
      }
    });
 
    this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
        this.updateNetworkStatus(ConnectionStatus.Online);
      }
    });
  }
 
  private async updateNetworkStatus(status: ConnectionStatus) {
    this.status.next(status);
 
    let connection = status == ConnectionStatus.Offline ? 'Offline' : 'Online';
    let toast = this.toastController.create({
      message: `You are now ${connection}`,
      duration: 3000,
      position: 'bottom'
    });
    toast.then(toast => toast.present());
  }
 
  public onNetworkChange(): Observable<ConnectionStatus> {
    return this.status.asObservable();
  }
 
  public getCurrentNetworkStatus(): ConnectionStatus {
    return this.status.getValue();
  }
}
```

And you can you this service in your component, for example:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NetworkService, ConnectionStatus } from 'src/services/network.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.page.scss'],
})
export class DashboardPage implements OnInit {
isOnline:boolean;

constructor(private network: NetworkService){}
  ngOnInit() {
  let status = this.network.getCurrentNetworkStatus();
  (status == ConnectionStatus.Offline)? this.isOnline = false: this.isOnline = true;
  console.log("Network status is ", this.isOnline);
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
<ion-row *ngIf="isOnline">
For online
</ion-row>
<ion-row *ngIf="!isOnline">
For Offline
</ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well.
I just get this code to continue the project. So, I know that we can deploy a version using the ionic dashboard. My problem is, I'm working on some new tasks, another branch, make some changes on the project, but when building the code for my device, my changes showed just for a while, when I close the app and reopen it, the device gets the version that I had before, without my changes. So I've noticed that it gets the last version deployed on the ionic dashboard. I sad about the connection to the internet, because if it's not connected, my changes still there.